# Angular dynamic model as array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following snippet of code and don't know how it should be organized to work properly. There is no documentation in official angular site but probably anybody know how handle it. Also I googled but it seams that there is no straightforward solution.

I have parameters array and each parameter is unique but has a parameter.name and possible items. Each parameter describe a Combo box. So I have a set of combo boxes and I have to collect all selected items in map associated array.

Example of input (just example, exact list of params I got from service):

```
      {{"route": ["1", "2", "3", "4"]},
       {"price": ["100", "200", 300"]},
       {"count": ["100", "200", 300"]}
```

It should be like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="parameter in parameters">
   <select name="select-1" ng-model="selected_params[parameter.type] }}">
      <option>
   </select>
 </div>
 Dynamic Result: {{ selected_params }}
```

And for example user put second and third check-box in second value and I got the response

```
  {"price" : "200", "count" : "200"}
```

Comment: you can't use expressions in `ng-model` , try using `[]` notation

Comment: If that's what you're getting, something is wrong.  You can't have an object that is just a list of objects, do you mean to have an array with objects that each have one key (i.e. `[{route:[]}, {price:[]} ]`?)  Otherwise your data doesn't make any sense.  If that is the case then do you have any control over how you get the data since it seems so messed up?

Comment: if selected_params is an object then this should work : `ng-model="selected_params[parameter.type]"`

Comment: seems this does not work

Comment: Set it in your controller.

Comment: How to do that correct in controller? Iterate over all checkboxes in page looks like not the best solution.